# MongoDB - Saving sub category details

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, routes

I would like to know how can I save my product details(sub category) inside an order details.
As for now, MongoDB only saves the ID of the product, without its details.

**Order Schema:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Product = require('../models/Product').schema

let Order = new Schema ({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    firstName: {type: String},
    lastName: {type: String},
    email:  {type: String},
    phone: {type: Number},
    address: {type: String},
    product: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: true}],
    createdAt:  {type: Date, default: Date.now}
},
{
    collection: 'orders'
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', Order);
```

**Product Schema:**

```js
// define the table structure for mongoDB
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Product = new Schema(
    {
         _id:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
        },
        product_Name:{
            type: String
        },
        product_Description:{
            type: String
        },
        product_Price:{
            type: Number
        },
        product_Img:{
            type: String
        },
        product_Quantity: {
            type:Number
        },
        id:{
            type: Number
        },

    }, {
            collection: 'products'
        }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', Product);
```

**Order routing (only post):**

```js
//create order
orderRoute.route('/').post((req, res) =>{
    Product.findById(req.body.productId)
    // .select('product')
    .populate('product')
    .then(product => {
        if(!product){
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: "product not found"
            });
        }
        const order = new OrderDetails({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            product:req.body.productId,
            email: req.body.email,
            firstName:req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            address: req.body.address,
        });
        return order.save()
        })
        
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            
            return res.status(200).json({
                
                message: "Order was Created",
                
                order:result,
                request:{
                    type:"GET",
                    order_url: "http://localhost:5000/order/" + result._id
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error:err.message
            });
        });
    
    });
```

**MongoDB doc:**

[image]

**GET method returns fully detailed order(from POSTMAN):

```js
{
    "message": "Order was fetched",
    "order": {
        "product": [
            {
                "_id": "5e1c9fc052b6b1b6b8fee292",
                "product_Name": "Soccer Ball",
                "product_Description": "Soccer Ball",
                "product_Price": 20,
                "product_Img": "./assets/accessories/soccerball.jpg",
                "id": 0,
                "product_Quantity": 1,
                "type": "accessories"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e5a6309d07a33280ce8c49d",
                "product_Name": "Air Pegasus 36",
                "product_Description": "Shoes 3",
                "product_Price": 80,
                "product_Img": "./assets/shoes/nike-mens air-zoom-pegasus-36-running-shoes.JPG",
                "id": 14,
                "product_Quantity": 1,
                "type": "shoes"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5eadacbf1260955398655ff7",
        "email": "tal",
        "firstName": "hhhhh",
        "lastName": "hhhh",
        "phone": 123,
        "address": "tal",
        "createdAt": "2020-05-02T17:24:15.419Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "GET",
        "all_orders_url": "http://localhost:5000/order"
    }
```

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by embeding documents.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

this approach is called denormaization and it will cause you data duplication in the product field, which may be needed in your case since the price of the product may change over time, but will make the products harder to manage in case you dropped the products collection.
I suggest that you keep the reference but add any data that might be changing to the order details collection.